# Error document (404) not working

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

The following is my htaccess code, please advise on what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.
I'm trying to add an error document. The 404 is in the root directory of the site.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|ico|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddLanguage en-US .html .htm .css .js
#Header unset ETag
FileETag none
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/javascript          js
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject   eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf          ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                   otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff         woff
    AddType image/svg+xml                   svg svgz 
    AddEncoding gzip                        svgz
</Ifmodule>
#Gzip
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
</ifmodule>
#End Gzip
```

Comment: What is inside `404.html` and how do you know its not working?

Comment: @anubhava it's just a little styled. When I type in a bogus address it takes me to the standard 404.

"Not Found

The requested URL /sh/showhaus_v2/about/asfdsf was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. And is `.htaccess` enabled?

Comment: @anubhava yeah it is. Everything else works, just not the 404

Comment: Ok can you try: `ErrorDocument 404 /`

Comment: @anubhava that takes me to my root website.

Comment: ok so that means `ErrorDocument 404` is working fine but due to some code in `404.html` it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use these codes in your .htaccess for capture 404 error pages.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /404.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now your all 404 requests will goto /404.html.
You can also use /404.php to code more dynamically.
Also make sure that rewrite module is enabled in your apache.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.But I had to modify that According to My need , As File not found error i was getting . My modified code : `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . 404Page.php [L]
</IfModule>`  .Anyway thanks . Feel free to browse my profile

Comment: Dynamic error documents should be avoided completely, just keep them static. If it's a server error or software error that's lead to the error being thrown, then you shouldn't try doing more dynamic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a direct link to the 404.html error page
viz.
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.php